# HADOOP - How To Dynamically Load Class in Map

Tags: java, reflection, hadoop, mapreduce

Be advised, this question answered itself after some careful review and was a bug.  Please consider this ticket informational.

I am working on a map reduce job where I want to pass a variable from the command line, to the  map.  This is so I can daynamically instantiate a custom parser via reflection.  However, instantiating the class leads to an NPE

`MRFileParser.java`

In main:

```
configuration.set("parser","com.example.parsers." + args[0])
```

In map:

```
Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
String parserClassName = configuration.get("parser");
Class parserClass = Class.forName(parserClassName);
fileParser = (FileParser) parserClass.newInstance()
```

But this throws null pointer exceptions:

```
attempt_201309161312_0020_m_000000_1: 2013-09-17 11:58:06.770 java[9623:1703] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
13/09/17 11:58:16 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201309161312_0020_m_000000_2,  Status : FAILED
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.encode(Text.java:388)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:178)
at com.example.MyMRFileParser$Map.map(MyMRFileParser.java:42)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

The class I am trying to load dynamically is compiled into the jar.  The `FileParser` is an interface that defines the parser contract, the name passed in on the command line is of a class that implements the `FileParser` interface.

My project layout looks like this:  Assume the package `com.example.someproject.*`

```
├── parsers
│   ├── FileParser.java
│   └── SomeSpecificFormatParser.java
├── mapreduce
│   └── MRFileParser.java 
├── model
```

└── SomeDomainSpecificClass.java

UPDATE: The problem turned out to be related to the next line `record = fileParser.toRecord(line);` where the parser parses the line into a record object.  Totally my bad.  I had omitted that.

Comment: Could you please share the entire trace?

Comment: Hi Tariq, its the same stacktrace, repeated three times, once for each attempt.

Comment: Then 13/09/17 `11:58:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1`

Comment: Also Im using hadoop-core 1.2.1 and the job setup looks like this: `        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(configuration, "Demo");`

Comment: Hello David..That looks OK. Anything interesting in TaskTracker logs??

Comment: I dont think so, theres nothign in this dir `/Users/dwilliams/Hadoop/tmp//hadoop-dwilliams/mapred/local/taskTracker/dwilliams/jobcache/`.  Is that the directory?  I looked for the pattern you mentioned yesterday `$ ls -Rlai ~/Hadoop/tmp/ | grep .log | grep task` but nothing came up.

Comment: The logs directory should be directly under your HADOOP_HOME. I guess /Users/dwilliams/Hadoop/logs...

Comment: I dont have a logs dir there.  The closest thing I have is this `$ cat ~/Hadoop/tmp/hadoop-dwilliams/mapred/local/userlogs/job_201309161312_0023/attempt_201309161312_0023_m_000000_0/stderr
2013-09-17 12:32:11.402 java[10126:1703] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.`  Do you have time for a chat?

Comment: Actually Im sorry, this question may be a dud.  It looks like the value is being passed.  Ill have an update with the cause of the error soon.

Comment: So I am dynamically trying to load a class based of that info, that part appears failing.  Here is the trace.  How would I do this? `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ...
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)`

Comment: The class I am trying to load dynamically is compiled into the jar.

Comment: I see..To be honest, I never had this kind of requirement. Let me try something so that I can answer correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-
1. The class FileParser is contained in a jar file.

1. Export hadoop class path

   export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=PATH_TO_JAR_FILE
2. Run map reduce job:

   PARAMS=com.example.someproject.FileParser

   hadoop jar $PATH_TO_JAR_FILE  com.example.someproject.MRFileParser $PARAMS
3. JobRunner.

   Configuration conf = new Configuration();
   conf.set("parser", args[0]);
4. Mapper (or reducer):

   Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();

   String parserClassName = configuration.get("parser");

   Class parserClass = Class.forName(parserClassName);

   fileParser = (FileParser) parserClass.newInstance()

Comment: Thanks @Archangel, that helped.  The problem turned out to be related to the next line `record = fileParser.toRecord(line);` where the parser parses the line into a record object, which I hadnt spotted until working through 4 above.  Totally my bad.  I had omitted that. Sorry, hope I didnt waste you time!